# Como inserir um HTML dentro de outro

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, asp

Simples, porém estou iniciando e acredito que vão me ajudar de forma objetiva.

Preciso inserir um menu e rodapé como se fosse um `#include` do [asp](/questions/tagged/asp), porém direto no HTML é possível?

Comment: Queres fazer isso no browser ou no servidor?

Comment: Pelo Browser, é um site HTML normal.

Comment: Include no HTML não dá. O que dá é pra usar iframes, ou carregar partes com JavaScript. Mas nenhuma das soluções é totalmente equivalente. Agora, é dificil um servidor de páginas que não tenha coisa do tipo. Mesmo o Apache, sem linguagem nenhuma instalada, tem server side includes.

Comment: Desculpem a ignorância, sendo por Includes ou JS, para executar os testes é melhor instalar o site no servidor e fazer por lá do que pelo local?

Comment: `HTML` e `JS` são renderizado da mesma forma estando em um servidor ou localmente, então não ha necessidade de subir pro servidor para testar.

Comment: Obrigado! Vou continuar pesquisando